# Is there a way to reduce a nested json by extracting only certain values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following, nested, json structure:

```
{
  element: "a",
  items: ["l1", "l2"],
  children: [{
    element: "b",
    children: [{
      element: "c",
      items: ["l3"]
    }, {
      element: "b",
      child: {
        element: "c",
        items: ["l4"]

      }
    }
```

Basically:

- An "element" contains a name, a list of items, and a list of children being an "element" themselves
- The items list can be missing

I'd like to process this json to get a flat array containing all the items:

```
const finalArray = parse(json); //returns ["l1","l2","l3","l4"]
```

Is there any elegant way to achieve this with mapping/filter functions?

Comment: That is not a valid object.

Comment: That is not a json, the field names should be wrapped with double quotes `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getItems = (acc = [], { items = [], child = {}, children = [] }) => 
  [
    ...acc, 
    ...items, 
    ...(child?.items || []),
    ...(children.length ? children.reduce(getItems, acc) : [])
  ];

const data = { 
  element:"a",
  items: ["l1","l2"],
  children: [ 
    {
      element: "b",
      children: [
        { element: "c", items: ["l3"] },
        { element: "b", child: { element: "c", items: ["l4"] } }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
console.log( getItems([], data) );
```

Comment: what kind of magic is that? :D Can you also suggest me a good tutorial to understand what you wrote?

Comment: @Phate you can start with basic recursion and es6